# Why is this counterexample wrong? (Theorem about Open subsets and Open relative to)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin, Theorem 2.30 states that:

> Suppose $Y \subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E = Y \cap G $ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

I've thought of the following "counterexample":

If $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $Y = ([0,2],0)$, $G = B_1(0)$ (i.e. the open ball of radius 1 centered at 0), then the theorem implies that $E = Y \cap G = ([0,1),0)$ is open relative to $Y$, which it is clearly not (due to $(0,0) \in E$).

Could someone point out why this "counterexample" is wrong?

Edit:

Here is the definition of "Open Relative to":

> $E$ is open relative to $Y$ if for each $p \in E$ there is an associated $r>0$ such that $q \in E$ whenever $d(p,q) < r$ and $q\in Y$.

Comment: In many expositions, the statement you've given is actually the **definition** of relative open (especially in topology).  If Rudin makes this a theorem, what is his definition of relative open?  Answerers would need this in order to answer your question correctly.

Comment: Why does $(0,0) \in E$ meany $E$ is not open relatively to $Y$?????

Comment: On notation: You should write $Y=[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and $E=[0,1)\times \{0\}.$

Comment: @fleablood Yes, it should still be open relative (mistake on my part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That fact that $(0,0) \in E$ doesn't make Rudin wrong.  The set $[0,0.5)$ is an open neighborhood in $Y$ about $(0,0)$ that is contained in $E$, so $(0,0)$ is an interior point of $E$.

Note that this line of reasoning fails in $X$ because there an open set about $(0,0)$ will contain a ball that leaves the $x$-axis, and for sure, $E$ is not open in $X$.

Edit:  seeing your updated question with the definition, it seems you've ignored the very important clause "and $q \in Y$."

Comment: He is not concluding it from **definition**. It is a **theorem** in Rudin.

Comment: Amended to give an explicit neighborhood.

Comment: At any rate, @user170039 makes a point:  we have to know the definition of "relative open" in order to answer this.

Comment: @Randall Edited to include the definition of "relative open". Thank you; I understand why the "counterexample" was wrong.

Comment: @SeanLee  Excellent.  Yours is a common misconception that nearly everyone has when first learning.  Good to clear it up now.

Comment: @Randall Sorry, I've taken a closer look at the definition of "open relative to", and it implies the existence of an r > 0 for every point p in E. In the "counterexample" above, there is no such r for the point (0,0). Could you provide some clarification for this? Thank you!

Comment: $r$ could be 0.5 as in my example.  You need to focus on $q \in Y$.

Comment: Ah I get it now, thank you for your patience (:

Comment: I sometimes teach math for theater majors. I have infinite patience.